# save image from bytes returned from android camera intent is saved as small image

Tags: android, android-intent, camera

I am trying to capture an image using Android Camera Intent. Camera intent returns Byte Array and when I saved the byte array as a Bitmap, I am getting a very small image instead of  getting an Image based on current camera settings (1024 Pixels currently set in the android mobile camera).

Usally i will get file path from the camera intent but somehow i am not getting from this device, so i am creating the bitmap from the byte returned by camera intent.

Anybody knows  why is this and how to solve this issue. Thanks.

The below is the java code block I am using.

private Intent cameraIntent = null;

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
              super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
                                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {  
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
      if ( data != null)
        {
           Bitmap myImage = null;
           Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
           ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,stream);
           byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
           BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
           myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,byteArray.length, options);
           fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sPath);
           BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
           myImage.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
           bos.flush();
           bos.close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.getExtras("data")` only returns a thumbnail image.  To obtain the full-sized image, you need to pass the camera intent a file in which to store that image and later retrieve.  A rough example follows.

Start the intent:

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/dcim/myappname");
File mFile = File.createTempFile("myImage", ".png", dir);

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mFile));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
```

Inside `onActivityResult`:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
   Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
}
// do whatever you need with the Bitmap
```

Keep in mind that mFile will have to be global or somehow persisted so that it may be called upon where necessary.